# method as an argument?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to write code that does something like this:

```
move = Exit.new(exit_type)
move.scan(person)
move.scan(person)
number_of_people = move.total
```

when more than 3 people exit the 'exit_type' knocks removes one person,
so if 1 or 2 people exit it stays the same, but if 3 or more than the 1 person is removed from the total.

how would i go about writing an 'exit_type' method within the Exit class initialize method as an argument? I hope this makes sense, I am more than happy to clarify for you.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: I guess you want to pass a lambda

Comment: A `Proc` or an explicit call to a `method` might be in order, but why do you want `exit_type` to be a method in the first place? Just pass in a number, and the class should be initialized accordingly. Or am I missing something?

Comment: looks like the same question you already asked - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19872212/ruby-excercise-whats-the-proper-solution - based on the other question I don't think you need to pass a method as an argument, but not sure - however, I am wondering do you understand how a ruby object gets initialized and what an instance variable is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hop you want to change the nature of scan member function with exit_type

```
class Exit
    attr_accessor :exit_type

    def initialize(exit_type = nil)
        @extit_type = exit_type
        end

    def scan(person)
        send(@exit_type || :default_exit_type_handler)
    end

    def default_exit_type_handler
        #your code
    end

    def exit_type_1
            #your code
    end
```

now you can initialize exit object as
    move = Exit.new(:exit_type_1)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure I understand the requirements, but it could just be due to poor naming.

My first spin would simply remove the need for callers to understand implementation details, e.g.,

```
mover = Exit.remove_only_after(3)
```

Internally, `Exit` would construct an instance using a symbol or whatever that could be checked in the `scan` method. This way you only need to know the *behavior* you want, instead of a method name, a symbol, or whatever, that actually implements that behavior.

Depending on actual needs, I might refactor it internal to `Exit` and use some form of strategy pattern, but it might be overkill. It really depends on how different the behaviors are, and how complex they are.